# Version of \left and \right that ignores subscripts and superscripts

Tags: math-mode, automation, parentheses

How can I define a macro (or macros) that works in an automatic way like the primitives `\left` and `\right`, but does not consider the space below or above operators like `\sum` or `\bigcup`?

This modified left and reight `\mleft`/`\mright` should work like
`\[\Bigl(\sum_i^j\Bigr)\]` if the input is `\[\mleft(\sum_i^j\mright)\]`, whereas the original `\left`/`\right` produces `\[\Biggl(\sum_i^j\Biggr)\]`.

While I already have a solution (s.b.), it has some caveats and there might be a better approach.

Comment: Have a look at nath package

Answer (score 1):

The following macro `\lrm` works by first using a `\vphantom` with the actual content of the parentheses to get the correct overall line height. Then it calls `\left` and creates another `\vphantom`, but this time it changes the catcodes and redefines `^` and `_` to mean `\relax`. Finally it actually outputs the content within a `\smash` just before the call to `\right`. Because of `\smash` the line height does not increase.

```
\begingroup
\catcode`_=\active
\catcode`^=\active
\gdef\lrm#1#2#3{%
 \vphantom{#2}%
 \left#1%
 \vphantom{
   \begingroup
   \def\sb##1{\relax}%
   \def\sp##1{\relax}%
   \def_##1{\sb{##1}}%
   \def^##1{\sp{##1}}%
   \catcode`_=\active
   \catcode`^=\active
   \scantokens{ #2\endinput}%
   \endgroup
  }
  \smash{#2}
  \right#3%
}

\gdef\mleft#1#2\mright#3{\lrm{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\gdef\mmleft#1#2\mmright#3{\lrm{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\gdef\mmmleft#1#2\mmmright#3{\lrm{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\endgroup
```

This solutions has some caveats:

- Sub- and superscripts within macros are not detected (`\expandonce` within the `\scantokens` helps, but would break most nested applications).
- `\mleft`/`\mright` cannot be nested, but nesting `\lrm` is possible.
- `\scantokens` requires eTeX (i.e. pdftex,luatex,xetex ...).
- If used for parentheses surrounding a fraction with two sums, the resulting parentheses may look too small.